# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML breaks JSON config with & character

Tags: next.js, google-optimize, amp-analytics

I am trying to put amp-analytics script into amp page generated from Next.js, but dangerouslySetInnerHTML breaks JSON config because of & character.

Here is the code:

```
<amp-analytics id='analytics1' type='googleanalytics'>
  <script type='application/json' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
    {
      "vars": {
        "account": "XX-XXXXXXXX-X"
      },
      "requests": {
         "experiment": "\${pageview}&xid=\${xid}&xvar=\${xvar}"
      }
    }
  ` }} />
</amp-analytics>
```

And here is the result:
[image]

As you can see the & character was converted to \u0026 and now amp-analytics tag doesn't work.

I also tried this:

```
<amp-analytics id='analytics1' type='googleanalytics'>
  <script type='application/json' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
    {
      "vars": {
        "account": "XX-XXXXXXXX-X"
      },
      "requests": {
         "experiment": "${JSON.stringify('${pageview}&xid=${xid}&xvar=${xvar}')}"
      }
    }
  ` }} />
</amp-analytics>
```

But got not valid JSON (with right & symbol)
[image]

Any ideas on how can I solve this?

As It turned out it happens because of AMP Optimizer in Next.js — github.com/ampproject/amp-toolbox/pull/649 And now I have to find a solution for that case

Comment: Just remove the quotes around `${JSON.stringify(...)}` in your second try.

Comment: @Al.G., in that case, I get the same result as in the first try. I also tried to reproduce it in different sandboxes — react, react with amp, next.js sandbox — and everywhere it works just fine, it returns valid and right JSON. Not sure why in my project it doesn't work well

Comment: Looks like it is next.js amp-optimizer issue because it works fine on non-amp pages...

Comment: Ok, then I have no idea what might be causing this. Rollbacked my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, given that all you want to do is set the text content. `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is required only if you need to parse HTML into DOM nodes.

You can set the text content like this:

```
<script type='application/json'>
  {JSON.stringify(
    {
      vars: {
        account: 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X',
      },
      requests: {
        experiment: `${pageview}&xid=${xid}&xvar=${xvar}`,
      },
    }
  )}
</script>
```

If you do it this way, React is smart enough to know that HTML entities aren't required in `script` tags, so those `&`s won't be escaped (unlike if it was a normal HTML element such as `div` ).

You can verify that like this ([demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-html-escaping-fdgug)):

```
const InnerHtmlLogger = ({ TagName }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(TagName, ref.current.innerHTML);
  }, [TagName]);

  return (
    <TagName ref={ref}>
      {JSON.stringify({
        '&': '&&',
        '&&&': ['&&&&', '&&&&&']
      })}
    </TagName>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <InnerHtmlLogger TagName='div' />
      <InnerHtmlLogger TagName='script' />
    </>
  );
}

// Log output:
// div {"&amp;":"&amp;&amp;","&amp;&amp;&amp;":["&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;","&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;"]}
// script {"&":"&&","&&&":["&&&&","&&&&&"]}
```

Comment: As It turned out it happens because of AMP Optimizer in Next.js — https://github.com/ampproject/amp-toolbox/pull/649
And now I have to find a solution for that case

Comment: Can you confirm you have the same issue even when not using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? Also, escaping with `\uXXXX`-style sequences shouldn't make any difference when parsing the JSON, given that `JSON.parse(String.raw\`"\u0026"\`) === JSON.parse('"&"')`.

Comment: Yes. All you variants return a valid JSON, but in my project with Next.js htmlEscape in AMP Optimizer changes it before rendering — https://github.com/ampproject/amp-toolbox/pull/649/files#diff-d73be5720aa6d0594a6ea82a87e7ba6c

Comment: And does that make the JSON parse incorrectly? The literal string representation of a JSON can change quite a lot without affecting its semantics. For example, `{ "a": "___", "a": "\u0026", "b": 1e+3 }` should be parsed exactly the same as `{"a":"&","b":1000}`.